# EF 4.1 POCO query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

I have this POCO and I want to return a list of the users in a particular company.

```
public class Company
{
    public AccreditedCompany() 
    {
        this.Branches = new HashSet<Branch>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }         
}

public class Branch
{
    public Branch() 
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }  
}

public class User 
{

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public string ComputerSN { get; set; }
    public string CameraSN { get; set; }

    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }         
}
```

This is my LINQ query:

```
var company = (from u in objDataContext.Companies.Include(c=>c.Branches.Select(v=>v.Users)) 
    where u.CompanyId == 8 select u).FirstOrDefault();

IQueryable<User> users = (from j in company.Branches select j.Users);
```

I have this compilation error on the second query:

> Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'
>   to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

I want to get a list of the users, similar to a plain SQL statement like

```
SELECT dbo.Users.* FROM Branches 
INNER JOIN dbo.Users ON dbo.Branches.BranchId = dbo.Users.BranchId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Companies ON dbo.Branches.CompanyId = dbo.Companies.CompanyId
WHERE     (dbo.Companies.CompanyId = 8)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your SQL query can be simplified: `SELECT dbo.Users.* FROM Branches 
INNER JOIN dbo.Users ON dbo.Branches.BranchId = dbo.Users.BranchId 
WHERE dbo.Branches.CompanyId = 8` You don't need to join into `Companies` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user query could be:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = company.Branches.SelectMany(branch => branch.Users);
```

This will return all users in any branch of the company.

Comment: In this case, you'll still need a query to get the target company.

You don't really need to involve the Company as the Branch object has access to companyID already. Start the query from Branch and you avoid a join in the resulting SQL Query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you could just use:

```
IQueryable<User> users = objDataContext.Users
                         .Where(u => u.Branch.CompanyId == 8);
```

I notice you have both `Company` and `CompanyId` on your `Branch` entity, though. That seems redundant, even though it simplifies this query slightly. You should be able to get rid of `Branch.CompanyId` and `User.BranchId` and just use the entity associations.

Comment: Thanks, i have the property to avoid loading navigation context. i can simiply querry a branch with its company id, without loading or including the company in the query.